# Need help with a JavaScript function to de-select items in jQuery DropdownChecklist

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I'm working on an ASP.Net webpage which will use the jQuery Dropdown Checklist (http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/). I'm fairly inexperienced with JavaScript and completely new to jQuery.

Could anyone help me with a JavaScript function that de-selects items from a jQuery DropdownChecklist?  It would need to accept a string, then de-select the item that matches that string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the original `<select>` element so that the item you want to deselect is no longer selected and then refresh the jQuery dropdown-checklist using the "refresh" command. Something like this (where `selectID` is the ID of the original `<select>` element and `targetString` is the content of the `<option>` you want to deselect):

```
function deselect(selectID, targetString){
  $("#"  + selectID + " option").each(function(){
      if($(this).text() === targetString) $(this).attr("selected", "");
  });
  $("#" + selectID).dropdownchecklist("refresh");
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think this will do exactly what I need.  Just curious though, how do you pass multiple parameters to a JavaScript function using the onClientClick event? --here's what I have:   OnClientClick='deselect("s1","<%#Eval("filterName") %>");'

Comment: No problem. If you like the answer be sure to up-vote it. If you want to deselect multiple options you could make targetString an array (targetStrings) so the data passed to it would be ["target1", "target2"] and change `=== targetString` to `in targetStrings`

Comment: That's handy, but I just need it to de-select one at a time at the moment.  Do I have the syntax right for calling the JavaScript function using OnClientClick?  Its not working at the moment and according to Firebug the JavaScript function isn't even being called.

Comment: I don't know ASP.NET, so I couldn't tell you.

Comment: ah, ok.  No problem.  I'll keep fiddling with it, but I think your function is what I needed.  Thanks.  I'll mark it as the answer as soon as I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Following code deselects item and removes it from display.

```
document.clearSel = function(list,txt){
  var ele=document.getElementById(list);
  for(i=0; i < ele.options.length; i++ ) {  
    if (ele.options[i].selected && (ele.options[i].text == txt) && 
                                      (ele.options[i].value != "")) {
        var val=ele.options[i].value;
        $("div#ddcl-" + list +"-ddw input[value='"+val+"']").each(function(){
            $(this).attr("checked",false);
            var spSel="span#ddcl-" + list +" span.ui-dropdownchecklist-text";
            var spTxt=$(spSel).text();          
            $(spSel).text(spTxt.replace(txt+",",'').replace(txt,''));
        });
     }
  } 
}

document.clearSel("s8","Low");
```

I got "div#ddcl--ddw input[value='']" and "span#ddcl- span.ui-dropdownchecklist-text" selectors after examining [demo page](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html) for *drop down check list*

PS:- I've trie  `$("#" + list).dropdownchecklist("refresh");` but I am not able to refresh the text;